# How should I plot a scatterplot with categorical data using Bokeh and Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing data as such:

```
Merchant | Non-Merchant | Num of Chats Received | Num of Chats Made
1        | 0            | 80                    | 50
0        | 1            | 60                    | 30
1        | 0            | 70                    | 40
0        | 1            | 50                    | 20
```

I want to be able to plot two different types of users (Merchants, Non-Merchants) on a Scatterplot comparing them for [Num of Chats Received, y axis].

In the data above,

Merchants are those marked '1' in the Merchants column and

Non-Merchants are those marked '1' in the Merchants column,

it is binary, there is no [1,1].

I'm new  to Bokeh and Data Viz in general, assuming Bokeh is my preferred method, how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with bokeh

CODE:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import pandas as pd

data = {'Merchant':[1,0,1,0],
        'Non-Merchant':[0,1,0,1],
        'Num of Chats Received':[80,60,70,50],
        'Num of Chats Made':[50,30,40,20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

merchant_chats_made = list(df[df['Merchant'] == 1]['Num of Chats Made'])
merchant_chats_received = list(df[df['Merchant'] == 1]['Num of Chats Received'])
non_merchant_chats_made = list(df[df['Non-Merchant'] == 1]['Num of Chats Made'])
non_merchant_chats_received = list(df[df['Non-Merchant'] == 1]['Num of Chats Received'])

output_file('merchant.html')

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.circle(merchant_chats_made,
         merchant_chats_received,
         size=10,color='red',alpha=0.5,
         legend='Merchant')

p.circle(non_merchant_chats_made,
         non_merchant_chats_received,
         size=10,color='blue',alpha=0.5,
         legend='Non-Merchant')

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Chats Made'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Chats Received'
p.legend.location = 'top_left'

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @rbierman , I gave it a try but my plot is blank ): any idea why? https://gist.github.com/rphly/dda99854a77e2fcc1b9c94fe2ef38ea1

I should mention that my values range from single digits to 800~.

Comment: SOLVED! Went to check for dtypes and realized my 1's & 0's were string types. Thank you!

Comment: oh, nice! If you're happy with this answer please accept it so the question closes